# Error while dll load

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, memory-leaks

My program tries to load some dlls. The problem doesn't come during the first load. But it comes every 7th time. I guess there is memory corruption. Is there a tool or something to debug the memory corruption for visual c++. I tried some memory leak tools but there is no memory leaks.

please help!!!

regards,
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog that goes through some steps you can use to find memory corruption.  The one that will really help is the gflags one (#2).

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/loufranco/archive/2007/02/06/6-_2200_Pointers_2200_-on-Debugging-Unmanaged-Code.aspx

> Use Debugging Tools for Windows: If you don't have this, go get it now. For some serious debugging, you get windbg, which I will write a blog about soon. But, the utility I use most is GFLAGS. One of the most useful features it has is the ability to make every heap allocation on its own page (+hpa).  This means that you can detect a memory out of bounds error at the point of the initial dereference, not later when you end up scribbling on something important.
>
> This option makes your process use much more memory and is noticeably slower.  I recommend running your entire unit test suite in the debugger after running this line from the command prompt (if you are using the NUnit gui test runner).
>
> ```
>  gflags -i nunit-gui.exe +hpa
> ```
>
> Replace nunit-gui.exe with the name of your test runner .exe.  (remember to turn it off when you are done with -hpa).  More on GFLAGS.
>
> WinDBG is essential for tracking down unmanaged memory leaks. You could also check out AutomatedQA's tools for this which are orders of magnitude easier to use -- I still think it's worth learning WinDBG though.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is to compile and run the program from the Visual Studio IDE using its `Debug` configuration.  This enables some heap checking and other options that might just show up the error right away.

Make sure you are compiling with all warnings (`/W4`) and that you neither ignore them, nor add casts to make them go away.  The compiler is a good friend if you listen to it.

Since it does not happen every time, this could be timing-related, or an uninitialized variable that usually gets left floating at some functionally OK value.